# HTML email template width 100% not working in gmail

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-templates

I'm trying to create a html email template and when i test my template i noticed i cannot get my template to have 100% in width. There's a empty area that my div does not extend to.

[image]

my html code

```
                        "<html style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px; min-width:100% !important; margin: 0;\">" +
                        "<head>\n" +
                        "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" />\n" +
                        "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n" +
                        "<title>Spokk email service</title>\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
                        "@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "</style>\n" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; min-width: 100%!important; height: 100%; line-height: 1.6em; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;\" bgcolor=\"#f6f6f6\">" +
                        "Mom" +
                        "</body/>"+
                        "</html>
```

The quotes are there because i'm using this in a java file. How can i get my email template to 100% width.

**This issue is only in gmail mobile app. In web the email is shown correctly**

Comment: Check the parent component of that component, it's the size of that one that decides how far the "100%" will take you

Comment: Gmail has margin on the left and right of the screens so emails are never touching the edges - could this not be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue before in Gmail, both on iOS and Android.

I'm using the following code to remove mobile Gmail's gutters in the email's CSS reset and it seems to do the trick:

```
<style>
/* iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S, 5C, and 5SE */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {
    u ~ div .email-container {
        min-width: 320px !important;
    }
}
/* iPhone 6, 6S, 7, 8, and X */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {
    u ~ div .email-container {
        min-width: 375px !important;
    }
}
/* iPhone 6+, 7+, and 8+ */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) {
    u ~ div .email-container {
        min-width: 414px !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

I know these say "iPhone" in the comments, but that's just a reference to describe the size the device viewport. You can create more of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix.